# How to enable $_POST in php

Tags: php, variables, post, get

in my server $_GET[] is work but $_POST[] is not work.

i'm use PHP Version 5.3.3 , centos .
pleas tell me how to enable Post,
always_populate_raw_post_data   On
post_max_size   200M

ex code where post is not work.

> j.php?b=`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg`

if use

> $_GET["b"] show = `http://stackoverflow.com/questi`

if use

> $_POST["b"] show =  (is echo nothing.)

My Real Code is
2 iframe 
1 iframe

```
<IFRAME SRC="http://hi.com/j.php?b=http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21571742/dcfzdczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxc" FRAMEBORDER="0" SCROLLING="no" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" WIDTH="160" HEIGHT="600"></IFRAME>
```

in these iframe i have no 2 iframe

```
<IFRAME SRC="http://ad.com/show.php?b='. $_GET["b"] . '&pubclick=[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]" FRAMEBORDER="0" SCROLLING="no" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" WIDTH="160" HEIGHT="600"></IFRAME>
```

Comment: You must create a form with method="POST"

Comment: where i make it.
i'm use it for pass a big size url not in any  form

Comment: You are making a GET request and trying to use POST tequest???

Comment: @user3143813 Gown gave you an example. You must create a standalone HTML page. And call your script from it.

Comment: i need to get data from url .GET can't echo the full url may its to long so GET can't echo. any other way to gate data from url ????

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<form method="post">
...
</form>
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

POST is used to get submitted data from a form's input.
GET is generally used to get data from url.
so to get POST to work, you need to pass values from Form's input fields

Hope this answers your qeustion!!

try this
pagewtihlink.php

```
  <a href="http://localhost:8888/test/next.php?b=1&p=2&ch=&cps=&c=2&l=INh=778f11eb876850b978be52ca49ac4ce8&t=139158‌​8943819">a link</a>

next.php

    <?php

$mylink = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $mylink;
?>
```

Comment: i need to get data from url .GET can't echo the full url may its to long so GET can't echo. any other way to gate data from url ????

Comment: what part of url do you need to echo?? @user3143813

Comment: what i load in b url variable.
j.php?b=http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21571742/dcfzdczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxcxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczczxczxczxczxczxczxczczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczczxczxczczczczxczczczczc/u=
so i need echo http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21571742/dcfzdczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxcxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczczxczxczxczxczxczxczczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczxczczxczxczczczczxczczczczc/u=

Comment: try this!!
$requiredurl = $_GET['b'];
echo $requiredurl;

Comment: check that post on @ghost comment. that might give you some idea

Comment: actual url is
site.com/cr?b=1&p=2&ch=&cps=&c=2&l=INh=778f11eb876850b978be52ca49ac4ce8&t=1391588943819&u=
with your $requiredurl echo only site.com/cr?b=1

Comment: @ashish 
GET:Requests data from a specified resource 
AND
POST:Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

Comment: because there is "&" right after 1 in the requiredurl which will be taken as a new variable. :)

Comment: oho so how to pass the url with "&" have any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) , and say what output it gives .

Comment: i try var_dump($_POST) and  print_r($_POST) not work echo nothing

Comment: Hey you are passing GET parameter value via uri in iframe and  trying to retrieve the value in $_POST, it wont work my friend."$_POST" is for fetching the value when passed via form submission. in other case you can try $_REQUEST (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Your question just gave me a mild anyorism. But is this what you mean?

```
$somethingcool = $_POST['somethingcool'];
```

Also as the others state; make sure you have this in relevant mark-up:

```
<form method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing variable in querystring so you can fetch this variable using $_GET or $_REQUEST. but if you want to use $_POST then you need to post form data using post method.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you want to pass is INSIDE the URL, then it will appear in `$_GET`. There is no way to put it into `$_POST` in this case.

A browser request will only ever populate `$_POST` in these cases:

- a HTML form sent with method "post" and default mimetype `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.
- an Ajax request with method "post" and the very same content-type header as the HTML form.

There is no way to send a post if all you have is a link (as in a html `href` or `src` attribute). If this leads to a too long URL, the content probably does not want to be included this way, or you should invent a way to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

request.php

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/test/next.php?b=1&p=2&ch=&cps=&c=2&l=INh=778f11eb876850b978be52ca49ac4ce8&t=139158‌​8943819">a link</a>
```

result.php

```
$mylink = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $mylink;
?>
```

this worked with me hope it works with you too :)
have a nice day!!